# What's wrong with the Java code below?

Tags: java, java-7

Here are the code.

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;

public class FileCopy{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String sourcePath=new String();
        String targetPath=new String();
        StreamTokenizer token=new StreamTokenizer(
                    new BufferedReader(         
                        new InputStreamReader(System.in)));
        int type=0;
        token.wordChars('*','*');
        token.wordChars(':',':');
        token.wordChars('/','/');
        token.wordChars('.','.');

        try{

            System.out.print("Please type in the source path:");
            if((type=token.nextToken())==StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD)
                sourcePath=token.sval;
            System.out.print("Please type in the target path:");
            if((type=token.nextToken())==StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD)
                targetPath=token.sval;
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Path source=Paths.get(sourcePath);
        Path target=Paths.get(targetPath);
        System.out.println("Please enter to create the sourcePath and the files...");
        Enter();
        Enter();

        createDir(source);

        String forResolve=new String();     
        for(int i=1;i<10;i++){
            forResolve=new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(i)).append(".txt").toString();
            createFile(source.resolve(forResolve));
        }

        System.out.println("Please enter to create the targetPath and the files...");
        Enter();

        if(Files.notExists(target))
            createDir(target);
        try(DirectoryStream<Path> contents=Files.newDirectoryStream(source,"*.*")){


            System.out.println("Please enter to start copying...");
            Enter();

            int count=1;
            for(Path temp:contents){

                copyFile(source, target.resolve(temp.getFileName().toString()));
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println("Copy files complete...");
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

        static void createFile(Path path){
            try{
                Files.createFile(path);
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    static void createDir(Path path){
        try{
            Files.createDirectories(path);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static void Enter(){
        try{
            System.in.read();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static void copyFile(Path source, Path target){
        try{                    
                Files.copy(source, target);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The purpose of the code is to copy files in the source directory to a target directory. Yet, when I run the program, what I got in the target directory are some folders with the same names as that of the files in the source directory. In other words, if there is a file name "hello.txt" in the source directory, there would be a folder name "hello.txt" in the target directory after I run the program. Anyone can tell me what's wrong with the code above? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you step through your program in a debugger as it doesn't apepar to do what you think. Also I would use Scanner or a plain BufferedReader rather than StringTokenizer.

Comment: Vote to close: Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should identify (or at least isolate) the problem by using a debugger or print statements, and then come back with a more specific question (once you've narrowed it down to a 10-line [test-case](http://sscce.org)).

Comment: You invent the wheel :). Use [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyDirectoryToDirectory(java.io.File, java.io.File)). You have source code there too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like main problem iis in determining target path and then this method

```
static void createDir(Path path){
        try{
            Files.createDirectories(path);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

works wrong and creates the whole path as directories.